# how to solve the uniformly distribution problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

The bus arrives at the station every $45$ minutes in the time interval from $7am$ to $7pm$. The person at the station comes in order. The time that the person will wait is uniformly distributed in this time interval.

$a)$ graphically represent this distribution

$b)$ what is the probability that the random person will wait more than $10$ minutes

$c)$ what is the probability that the random person will wait in the interval of (10-20min)

My attemp is: let $X$ its time that the random person comes in station, $X\thicksim U(0,720)$

$a)$

[image]

but I don't know if the graph is good, or if something else needs to be added

$b)$ $$P(X\in(0,5)\cup(15,20))=P(0<X<5)+P(15<X<20)=\int_0^5\frac{dx}{720}+\int_{15}^{20}\frac{dx}{720}=\frac{1}{72}$$
but I don't know if the solution is good

$c)$ $$P(X\in (10-20min))=P(10<X<20)=\int_{10}^{20}\frac{dx}{720}=\frac{1}{72}$$
but I don't know if the solution is good.

Help me please. Thanky very much for my hard

Comment: can anyone help me, or in part $b)$ its interval $(0,45)\cup (55,100)$

Comment: Please do not use flags to communicate with the author of comment or post. This does work. The content of flags is seen only by moderators not the author of the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bus comes at the times of $45i$ for $i=0,1,\cdots ,15$ in the time interval $[0,720]$ (note that $720=45\times 16$), therefore the probability of b) becomes $$P=\Pr \left\{\bigcup_{i=0}^n45i<X<45(i+1)-10\right\}=\sum_{i=1}^n\Pr\{45i<X<45i+35\}$$

For part c) similarly that is 
$$P=\Pr \left\{\bigcup_{i=0}^n45(i+1)-20<X<45(i+1)-10\right\}=\sum_{i=1}^n\Pr\{45i+25<X<45i+35\}$$

Comment: where I interrupt the sequence of intervals, i.e., for part b) (0,35); (45,80), ...., or $$\int_0^{35}\frac{dx}{720}+\int_{45}^{80}\frac{dx}{720}$$

Comment: for part a); its ok

Comment: And also for the other two parts since each probability inside the $\sum$ represents an integral.

Comment: for part c) $$\int_{25}^{35}\frac{dx}{720}+\int_{70}^{80}\frac{dx}{720}$$

Comment: part b) $$\int_0^{35}\frac{dx}{720}+\int_{45}^{80}\frac{dx}{720}+\int_{90}^{125}\frac{dx}{720}+\int_{135}^{170}\frac{dx}{720}$$ or not, and                                                                                         for part c) $$\int_{25}^{35}\frac{dx}{720}+\int_{70}^{80}\frac{dx}{720}+\int_{115}^{125}\frac{dx}{720}+\int_{170}^{180}\frac{dx}{720}$$ or not

Comment: Why don't you consider the other integrals e.g. in part b) the integrals $$\int_{180}^{215},\int_{225}^{260},\cdots$$?

Comment: but which I take, and how much to take, just two intervals or more

Comment: All of which. Take all the integrals of form $$\int_{45i}^{45i+35}$$for $i=0,\cdots 15$ because the bus or the person can arrive at any time in $[0,720]$

Comment: similarly for part c) all

Comment: Yew. Also for part c)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106715/discussion-between-madrit-zhaku-and-mostafa-ayaz).